# $('body').scrollTop() Not provide a scroll position in iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I want to fetch current scroll position in "IPHONE" using jquery.

I used different types of solutions are below:

```
1) $('body').scrollTop()
2) document.body.scrollTop
```

But above both solutions are returning "0" in "IPHONE" instead of actual scroll position. Would you please let me know what is the issue with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you have checked body height, if not then please check it and set below in your css.

```
body {
    height:auto;
}
```

I had the same issue but with this, it was worked as charm.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
It's working for me. Thanks a lot !!